# What are the criteria for a question to appear in the "Hot Network Questions" section?

Tags: support, hot-questions

I am asking out of curiousity, because I believe there are many questions that should be there but they aren't.

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel. Btw why do you always target me :)

Comment: Some people are just everywhere :P